# can ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance return null?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, nullreferenceexception, service-locator

I have this piece of code (or similar) in many of our views:

```
private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

Constructor()
{
    eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
    ...
}
```

I read from [this](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/workitem/9676) post that ServiceLocator.Current can throw NullReferenceException (bad thing on a constructor) but I was wondering if the GetInstance<>() method can return null (or some other inconsistent object) making eventAggregator dangerous to use later in other methods.

***NOTE: I'm quite new to MVVM and WPF***

Comment: Technically if ServiceLocator.Current is Null, you will not be able to call the .GetInstance<T>() method, as you will receive an `Object not set to an instance of an object` exception.

Comment: After acquiring some experience with this, a situation were ServiceLocator.Current can be null could happen when invoking the code in a unit test. In this scenario, it is possible that the service locator have not been initialized (i.e. the code responsible for it might not be invoked). A work around is to mock it (I have used MOQ library), but just for testing that specific code where the service locator is present but we are not interested on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the servicelocator is null, then there is probably something not correctly setup for unity.  under normal circumstances it shouldnt be an issue imho.

having said that, i tend to use a slightly different way to get to the servicelocator.

for instance, if i have a class called MyClass i will use unity dependency injection to pass the servicelocator in ( also referred to as the container in unity ). And I tend to use the Resolve functionality of unity rather than GetInstance, but they are the same.

There is also talk that the servicelocator is an antipattern, but i dont buy into that line of thinking.
http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx

example

```
public MyClass(IUnityContainer container)
{
    var ea = container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
}
```